# Failed Assignment in Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

This problem seems kind of silly to me, and I really didn't want to ask it. But I am supposedly assigning a value to an array and that value is not changing when I do. I've tried this in both Chrome and Firefox.

```
alert(map[(faces[face].y-5)/10][(faces[face].x-5)/10]);
map[(faces[face].y-5)/10][(faces[face].x-5)/10]=' ';
alert(map[(faces[face].y-5)/10][(faces[face].x-5)/10]);
```

I've even tried replacing the face variable with the integer it contains and I get the same thing. The first alert shows up 'r' and the second alert shows up the same. The assignment on the second line is not occurring.

Comment: Edit your tags to include the language you're using

Comment: Actually, you just answered my question. I forgot that while I can get the value of a character with this notation, I cannot perform an assignment. I forgot that in javascript, a string is not an array of characters like it is in C++.